# How does one find the automorphism group of the following groups?

Tags: group-theory

An automorphism of a group G is an isomorphism of G in itself.

I am trying to find the automorphism groups of: $\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ p prime; $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

I know that any automorphism of G is defined by the image of the generating set of G. But I don't know where to go from there to find the group of automorphisms

Comment: Well, what is a good choice of generating set for these groups?

Comment: for $\mathbb{Z}$  1 and all prime numbers I believe. for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ 1 and all prime numbers smaller or equal to p and for $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ (1; 2;3;5)

Comment: Those seem like pretty bad choices for this purpose unfortunately. Try to find some smaller sets (like, with just one element for example).

Comment: @aribaldi for integers $\pm 1$ are the generators. No need of primes.

Comment: Oh true I was thinking of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ when we're talking about the additive group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ has generators $1,2,3,4,5,6$. Let $\psi$ be an automorphism. Then $\psi$ is entirely determined by where it sends a generator. So $\psi(1)$ is one of $1,2,3,4,5,6$. That choice determines the automorphism and every automorphism is determined by that choice. So there are 6 automorphisms. Furthermore, $\psi(n)=\psi(1)n$. So $\psi$ is the "multiplication by $k$" map, where $k=\psi(1)$ is one of the above 6 values.

Generalize this to get the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. For the latter group, note that there are only two generators.

**Edit:**
Explicitly, the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\psi$ where $\psi(1)=5$ is the map that takes $n\mod 7$ to $5n\mod 7$. This is a homomorphism of the group and has inverse $\xi$, where $\xi$ takes $n\mod 7$ to $3n\mod 7$. To check that they are inverses, note that $(\xi\circ\psi)(n\mod 7)=15n\mod7\equiv n\mod 7$.

Comment: Doesn't a cyclic group have a unique generator by definition?

Comment: No. A cyclic group of order $n$ has $\phi(n)$ generators, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. The uniqueness you may be thinking of is this: A cyclic group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each $d$ dividing $n$, and there are no other subgroups.

Comment: Also I don't understand what the explicit group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ are

Comment: @aribaldi I think the point of confusion here is that "a set of generators" is not the same as "a generating set". The first refers to the set of all elements which individually generate the group (so this only makes sense for cyclic groups as we have here), while the second is a set whose elements collectively generate the group.